# How to create DocPad plugin?

Tags: node.js, templates, plugins, content-management-system, docpad

I did all steps from [here](http://docpad.org/docs/plugin-write):

1) created simple plugin /plugins/myplugin/myplugin.plugin.coffee with this code:

```cs
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->
  class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin
    name: 'myplugin'
    renderBefore: ({templateData}) ->
      templateData.foo = 'bar'
```

2) /plugins/myplugin/package.json

```
{
  "name": "myplugin",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "./src/myplugin.plugin.coffee"
}
```

3) /src/documents/index.html.eco

```html
<p><%= @foo %></p>
```

But plugin doesnt work. It isn't in DocPad's log `info: Plugins: eco` and throws error `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`.

What did i miss?

Comment: I found a problem. Every DocPad plugin must have `"keywords": {"docpad-plugin"}` property in `package.json`, otherwise docpad ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

You have `/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.plugin.coffee` and then reference it with `"main": "./src/myplugin.plugin.coffee"` - which expectes the plugin file to be inside a `src` directory like so: `/plugins/myplugin/src/myplugin.plugin.coffee` - you'll need to correct one of these.

If you can link me to the place where the documentation confused this, I'll happily fix it.

DocPad also requires plugins to have the following inside their `package.json` file:

`"keywords": ["docpad-plugin"]`

Comment: I just didn't know about `"keywords": ["docpad-plugin"]`, this was the reason. myplugin.plugin.coffee was inside src/